# replace Windows short cuts for all programs

Tags: c#, service, hotkeys

is it possible to have my overrides take precedence system wide, so even when running a web browser, word editor, or paint program (my app would still be running in the Background or as a service obviously)

using Visual C# 2010

Sample of how I'm overriding in my code:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    if((keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
    {
         //your implementation
         return true;
    } 
    else if((keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))
    {
         //your implementation
         return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you give me a -1 please at least explain why

Comment: what you want is a global hook.  see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: can you please provide more information for your question. You want to capture keys?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use Global Hooks, [Global Mouse and Keyboard Hook](https://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) is an excellent library which simplifies the process. here is an example based on your question.

```
internal class KeyboardHook : IDisposable
{
    private readonly KeyboardHookListener _hook = new KeyboardHookListener(new GlobalHooker());

    public KeyboardHook()
    {
        _hook.KeyDown += hook_KeyDown;
        _hook.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void hook_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyCode ==  Keys.C && e.Control)
        {
            //your implementation
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true; //other apps won't receive the key
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode ==  Keys.V && e.Control)
        {
            //your implementation
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true; //other apps won't receive the key
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _hook.Enabled = false;
        _hook.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Usage sample:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        using (new KeyboardHook())
            Application.Run();
    }
}
```

Comment: `GlobalHooker` ??? Seriously? Jeez... we programmers should pay more attention when naming classes. On second thought: maybe they made it on purpose. It is in the "business" layer, I presume.